# Nginx Apache Restart Connection time out

Tags: apache, nginx, restart

Basically Nginx sits in the front end of the server running on port 80, Apache runs on port 8080 and Nginx delivers all incoming traffic via the proxy to apache. The issue is if I am to restart the apache web server or turn it off Nginx does not retry the connection or display a offline page it just keeps loading and loading until it times out.

Does anyone know how I can get Nginx to retry the connection or display a offline page when apache is restarting or offline ?

I did come across this but it was no help and unstable https://serverfault.com/questions/259665/nginx-proxy-retry-while-backend-is-restarting

Comment: Is apache fully operational when in the meantime your connection is waiting?

Comment: Apache is online but if i reboot it or turn it off i would like nginx to display a offline page or unable to connect (error message or something) rather than what it currently does what is time out.